# On debug of c program

Tags: c, debugging

I have a C program which throws segfault. However, as I use gdb to find out where the error is thrown. I get following stack info... I dont understand why #1 points to ??(). What is the possible reason for this? Thanks.

```
#0  __longjmp () at ../sysdeps/i386/__longjmp.S:68
#1  0x43746a57 in ?? ()
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to debug your program, you need to compile it with debugging symbols included, which you can do by using the `-g3` flag if compiling using GCC. When you run the debug version of your program in GDB and execute `bt` (for "backtrace") you should get a more sensible piece of output.

Comment: Thanks. I dont know if I understand correctly. I tried follows,
'gcc -g3 XXX'

and run gdb. after the crash and typing bt, gdb outputs exactly same things... no ideas now.

Comment: Hm.. it's possible that this crash is occurring in a library that you are using. In this case, you should change the linker rule to link against a debug version of the library. Alternatively, you can add some logging to track down roughly where this error is occurring. If you post a bit of code around there, that should allow us to spot the error. You can use google-glog for simple logging: http://code.google.com/p/google-glog/

Comment: Is it possible the exception is coming from os kernel? If that case, how should one debug? (I think I used the lib code compiled with -g)

I also find out if not in debug, sometimes segfault will not be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

gdb doesn't know the name of the function so it puts `??`.

have you tried compiling with debug symbols?

Answer (score 0):

If `longjmp()` goes astray as it seems it is, then the problem is likely that you're abusing it - either by passing a `jmpbuf` that was never initialized by a `setjmp()` call, or by passing a `jmpbuf` that was set in a routine that has since returned.

For how to find out more with debugging information, see the other answers and compiling with the `-g` option.